# I get error after using rails new command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get error after I use rails new command-

```
Pareshs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop psghodge$ rails new lynda_cms
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:32:in `default_options': undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:90:in `<class:Base>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:85:in `<module:Generator>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:48:in `<module:Rails>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/rails:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to follow a CMS tutorial on lynda.com which is quiet old and outdated. I would suggest following Rails Tutorial at https://www.railstutorial.org/book as it has been kept up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your error, you're trying to use Rails v2.3.5 with ruby 2.0.0.  Without doing a lot of googling I can't be certain, but I'm fairly sure that old versions of Rails like that only work with ruby 1.8.7.

Unless you have a **really** good reason to use a version of Rails that old, you shouldn't do it.

Use a new Rails, or if you have to use that Rails then install ruby 1.8.7